# SQL Server, How to group rows that are near in time

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that has a time value, and a user id, and I want to group the rows if they are near in time (less than 2 mn between each row), and group them by user id.

Here is an Example :

```
CreatedAt  | User ID
'16:01:01' | '01'
'16:02:20' | '01'
'16:03:20' | '01'
'16:04:20' | '01'
'16:05:20' | '02'
'16:06:20' | '02'
'16:07:20' | '02'
'16:08:20' | '02'
'16:14:02' | '02'
'16:15:01' | '02'
'16:20:02' | '03'
```

The result should be :
User ID = 01

```
'16:01:01'
'16:02:20'
'16:03:20'
'16:04:20'
```

User ID = 02

```
'16:05:20'
'16:06:20'
'16:07:20'
'16:08:20'

'16:14:02'
'16:15:01'
```

User ID = 03

```
'16:20:02'
```

I'm not even sure if it's doable by SQL, or I have to code it (I have few millions lines in my database so it's not the most effective way).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your desired result isn't very clear.   You want SQL Server to insert empty rows between the "groups"?   Sounds like something that should be done on the front end.

Comment: In this part "less than 2 mn between each row" what is mn? Is that minute? And agreed that your output is not clear at all.

Comment: The presentation was edited by an admin, so for UserID 2, I want 2 groups, thus the separation.
The mn is minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This assigns a "Group Number" to the sets. however, not sure what this really achieves, but might help you achieve what you want on your presentation layer:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT CONVERT(time(0), V.CreatedAt) AS CreatedAt, UserID
    FROM (VALUES ('16:01:01','01'),
                 ('16:02:20','01'),
                 ('16:03:20','01'),
                 ('16:04:20','01'),
                 ('16:05:20','02'),
                 ('16:06:20','02'),
                 ('16:07:20','02'),
                 ('16:08:20','02'),
                 ('16:14:02','02'),
                 ('16:15:01','02'),
                 ('16:20:02','03')) V(CreatedAt, UserID)),
TimeDiff AS(
    SELECT *,
           CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(SECOND,LAG(CreatedAt,1,CreatedAt) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY CreatedAt ASC),CreatedAt) <= 120 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Succession
    FROM VTE)
SELECT TD.CreatedAt,
       TD.UserID,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN TD.Succession = 0 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY TD.CreatedAt
                                                           ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS GroupNumber
FROM TimeDiff TD;
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, in the real case scenario I have other columns that will be needed.